# When does a UITableViewCell get displayed?

Tags: uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to create a blurred UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"Item %i Row %i Section %i", indexPath.item, indexPath.row, indexPath.section);
   // if (indexPath.row != 0) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.bounds.size, cell.opaque, 0.0f);
    [cell drawViewHierarchyInRect:cell.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImage *blurredCell = [snapshotImage applyBlurWithRadius:4 tintColor:[UIColor clearColor] saturationDeltaFactor:1.0 maskImage:nil];
    UIImageView *snapshotImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:blurredCell];
    [cell addSubview:snapshotImageView];
    //}
}
```

I could overlay it with a UIToolbar but that approach seems to slow down the scrolling massively. And the UIToolbar blurs the cell too much.

So, where in the cell lifecycle, if it all, can I put my blurring code?

Comment: the "`applyBlurWithRadius`" line is surely what's slowing down your scroll radically.  Can you cache or pre-crate those blurred images before you attempt to scroll them?  They get re-generated each and every time your cell appears.

Comment: the question isn' about performance, though. of course I could cache the images. I'm asking about WHEN to create them. Right now, this blurs the visible cells when the UITableView loads - the other cells are black.